# Why do I see error 504 for nationalrail.co.uk?

Tags: networking, http

I am trying to access [the official website for trains in the UK](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk), but I keep seeing a 504 - Gateway Timeout error on my laptop connected to wifi and then fiber. The site is up, as confirmed when I access the page via the phone network on my cell phone.
Therefore, I guess the error comes from my side an not from theirs. I have tried

- 3 different browsers
- disabling the firewall on my laptop (littlesnitch)
- restarting my router
- disabling my pihole ad blocker

What else could cause this error, and how could I further troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I would wonder if it's an IPv4 vs IPv6 issue.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the Mac & **all** network hardware. Try again.

Neither Little Snitch nor Pihole ought to be the cause. The chances are it's not actually your issue but something between you & them. Using the phone will just go a different route, over a different provider.

If it's only that site that's affected it pretty much already rules out your own node.

In all probability, just waiting until someone finds where the error actually is & fixing it will be the ultimate course of action.

In the meantime, you could try changing your DNS provider, try 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 or 1.1.1.1 & see if they've already found a route around the problem node.

You can always test using a service such as https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com but as you've already proven you can access it by a different route, that's not relevant in this particular case. I can confirm I can also reach it over a Virgin Media connection from London.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not provide enough information to get a precise answer. Trying these and sharing the results could prove useful for getting better answers:

- Start Windows in the safe mode and see if you can connect to the website this way.
- Again, on Windows, press `Start + S` keys, write `cmd` and hit `Enter` key. Then enter the command `ping nationalrail.co.uk` and see if the attempts are successful.
- Change your DNS settings (ex. Google DNS: 8.8.4.4 & 8.8.8.8) and see if that will make any difference.

**Edit:** Seems like you're using Mac. You can quickly search for the equivalents of the actions above in Mac and do as explained, and share the results.

Comment: The mention of Little Snitch tells us it's a Mac, not Windows.